# Sum Two columns If Other Columns Are Equal

Tags: python

I'm trying to use pandas to add columns Amount and Amount2 only if Account is in Account2.

input

```
 Account      Amount    Account2     Amount2
0   0001957331   409.50  0404618555    26.31
1   0404618555  1535.40  0490812351     5.31
2   0490812351   338.12  0521656066   787.94
3   0696978386    13.11  0696978386   700.55
```

expected output:

```
0001957331   409.50
0404618555  1561.71
0490812351   343.43
0696978386   713.66
```

my code:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(allc_acct_amt, columns=["Account", "Amount", "Account2", "Amount2"])
    print(df)
    dff = df.groupby(["Account","Account2"])[['Amount', 'Amount2']].sum().reset_index()
    print(dff)
```

Comment: The expected output of the third row and your question don' match up

Comment: @12944qwerty can you explain further? If Account is in Account2( or vice versa) then the script should add Amount+Amount2.

Comment: Account1 and Account2 in third row are not the same and the amount doesn't make sense with the rules yuou have

Comment: Also, what is the output that happens instead of your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `merge`:

```
out = pd.merge(df[['Account', 'Amount']], df[['Account2', 'Amount2']], 
               left_on='Account', right_on='Account2', how='left')

out = out.assign(Amount=out[['Amount', 'Amount2']].sum(1)) \
         .drop(columns={'Account2', 'Amount2'})
```

Output:

```
>>> out
      Account   Amount
0  0001957331   409.50
1  0404618555  1561.71
2  0490812351   343.43
3  0696978386   713.66
```

Setup to be reproducible:

```
data = {'Account': ['0001957331', '0404618555', '0490812351', '0696978386'],
        'Amount': [409.5, 1535.4, 338.12, 13.11],
        'Account2': ['0404618555', '0490812351', '0521656066', '0696978386'],
        'Amount2': [26.31, 5.31, 787.94, 700.55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mask = df["Account"] == df["Account2"]
df["total_amount"] = df["Amount"] + df["Amount2"][mask]
```

Comment: This doesn't agree with row 2 of the expected output.